# Error while building docker image on the server?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I am creating a docker image while building docker it failed to create container on windows and throws the following error. Can anyone help me to overcome this issue

```
FROM python:3.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y postgresql-client && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Error:

```
  Step 1/9 : FROM python:3.7
  ---> 0b21994a4758
  Step 2/9 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
  ---> Using cache
  ---> 925bec50f994
 Step 3/9 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y postgresql-client &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 Failed to unmarshall layerchain json - invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value
```

The above is the error I am getting. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Please provide `dockerfile` contents.

Comment: What contents i have to provide, I didn't get you exactly. Do I need to provide any other info?

Comment: When you say you build the docker image. How you did it? You got to have some file named `dockerfile`. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: docker build -t -name-v8 . like this i created doker image in aws

Comment: The directory where you ran `docker build` command, will  have a file named `dockerfile` in it. Please provide contents of that file.

Comment: FROM python:3.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y postgresql-client && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
EXPOSE 8000
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: can you update your question with this `dockerfile` contents and also the error you got while building the image will have the step number where exactly it failed. I mean onwhich line of dockerfile.

Comment: Weird I try to build it on my system it didn't break at step 3. On which OS are you running this.

Comment: Might be some problem with the file. Can you re-edit that step 3 again in that dockerfile. Maybe there was something wrong while editing the dockerfile.

Comment: windows.What you want me to edit in step 3?

Comment: I mean re-write this line `RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y postgresql-client && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

Comment: I tried building on ubuntu OS and the first 3 steps work fine. As suggested by mchawre plase redit line 3 . Check for any unnecessary tabs or spaces

Comment: If re-writing that line is not helping. You might have to look this https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/140 and also if possible try to restart docker.